# split large csv file into multiple small files in perl

Tags: perl, csv

I want to split a csv file into multiple small csv files using perl. My csv file contains:

16047710472 4

12899376478 3

14034211945 3

16132767680 4

17059884442 4

17808605446 3

15144433554 5

15145869428 4

12269245032 3
...
...

I want to break this file into small files using line-number.And the output file will be in dynamic name.For example the first output file name output1.csv and the second one will be output2.csv and so on depending on the no of output files.

Please give me some advise.

Comment: you can use `split` for that, assuming you're on a linux machine http://www.computerhope.com/unix/usplit.htm

Comment: If you know that there are no embedded newlines in the fields then you can use split, but for the generic case you'll need to use a CSV parser.: Here is a solution I wrote: http://perlmaven.com/split-csv-file-into-multiple-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV;
my $file = 'csv_with_newline.csv';

my $size = 3;

my $file_counter = 0;
my $line_counter = 0;

my $out;

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new ({ binary => 1, auto_diag => 1, sep_char => ';' });
open my $in, "<:encoding(utf8)", $file or die "$file: $!";
while (my $row = $csv->getline($in)) {
    $line_counter++;
    if (not $out or $line_counter > $size) {
        if ($out) {
            close $out;
            $line_counter = 0;
        }
        $file_counter++;
        my $outfile = "output$file_counter.csv";
        open $out, ">:encoding(utf8)", $outfile or die "$outfile: $!";
    }
    $csv->print($out, $row);
    print $out "\n";
}
close $in;
close $out;
```

For a detailed explanation see the article http://perlmaven.com/split-csv-file-into-multiple-files

(Disclaimer: I have written the article)

Comment: The format of csv file is not the expected one.it is as follows:

"16047710472,4                  "
"12899376478,3                  "
"14034211945,3                  "
"15145869428,4                  "
"12269245032,3                  "
"17789220731,4                  "
"12269795657,3                  "
"17788583770,4                  "
How to remove this string structure?

Comment: Please update the original post to reflect the file you need to split. Are there spaces between the numbers or commas? Are there quotes around the strings or not? Are there multiple such pairs on a line?
If you indent your code by 4 spaces it will show exactly as you typed it it.